# Connection Refused : IOException in android TCP/IP

Tags: android, tcp

im a newbie in android. I would like to ask if anybody knows why i'm getting this "connection refused" IOException when i try to establish a TCP/IP connection between two android device. I tried to ping both device and they are responding. Anybody  please... 
Thanks in advance...

```
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.4.100:8080 - Connection refused
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:219)
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:781)
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:316)
E/TCP_IP connect thread( 7466): at com.neugent.WIFI.TCP_IP$ConnectThread.run(TCP_IP.java:291)
```

Comment: Ping isn't as helpful.  Try telnet.  If you're on windows and in a cmd prompt, that would be: `telnet 192.168.4.100 8080`.  I'm pretty sure that will fail which indicates that nothing is listening on that port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the missing INTERNET permission, add this line to your  `Android.manifest`  file just above the  `<application>`  tag.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET/>`

Comment: Great! Don't forget to select an answer so that others may know what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the INTERNET permission? That, or your Wifi isn't turned on or the other IP isn't accessible (like you're trying to connect to a LAN IP via WAN).

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting my WIFI worked....