# HttpURLConnection.getInputStream always throws IOException in android 2.1

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

When attempting to open a connection on the android 2.1 platform, the HttpUrlConnection.getInputStream method always throws a IOException, FileNotFound exception.  The code works as expected in 2.2 and 2.3 version of Android.  I have a standard method for creating a new connection.  The error is thrown immediately after this when get input stream is called.  As a note, all of the connections attempting to be made are "http://something/something".

```
public static URLConnection createConnection(String urlStr, Boolean useAuthentication, Boolean setOutput){
        Log.i(GpodRoid.LOGTAG, "Creating Connection to " + urlStr);
        URLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = new URL(urlStr).openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(setOutput);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            if(useAuthentication){
                String auth = GpodRoid.prefs.getUsername() + ":" + GpodRoid.prefs.getPassword();
                String encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(auth.getBytes());
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","basic " + encoded);
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(GpodRoid.LOGTAG, "Error creating Connection: " + stackTrace(e));
        } 

        return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it opens the connection on 2.1 - I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work on > 2.1.

Could it be a missing permission in your `Android.manifest`. If yes, have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629495/connection-refused-ioexception-in-android-tcp-ip/5629852#5629852) ?

Comment: Okay. If you figure out the solution, do post it so others can find it useful. Thanks!